# Typo3: Inserting data during extension installation (after table creation)

Tags: php, installation, typo3

For a custom extension I'm writing, I have an ext_tables.sql file which is being loaded at installation time.

I would like to insert some dynamic data into the tables created from ext_tables.sql during the installation routine using PHP code. Is this possible? If so, what do I have to do and where do I have to do it?

Alternatively, is it possible to have PHP code create the tables (using the DB interface) during the installation rather than relying on ext_tables.sql? Again, if so, what do I have to do for this and where do I have to do it.

Comment: why not just add the inserts at the bottom of the ext_tables.sql file?

Comment: While that is possible, the values come from a configuration PHP class ... so the cleaner/proper way would be to dynamically insert these values after the tables have been created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can (with a litte trick):

1. Add an ext_conf_template.txt to your extension
2. Add an user-type entry to ext_conf_template.txt

   ```
   # cat=basic; type=user[EXT:<EXTNAME>/Path/To/Class.php:Tx_Path_To_Class->postInstall]; label=
   postInstallAction=0
   ```
3. Create to PHP-File Class.php in path /Path/To

   This method can be used to do some post install actions or more generally to modify
   the extension configuration page (The method could return HTML which will be included
   here).

   ```
   class Tx_Path_To_Class {
       /**
        * Generates and returns an message.
        *
        * @param array               $params      Name and value from ext_conf_template.txt
        * @param t3lib_tsStyleConfig $styleConfig Instance of config style editor
        *
        * @return string HTML code
        */
       public function postInstall(array $params, t3lib_tsStyleConfig $styleConfig) {
           // Do your stuff
           return '';
       }
   ```

   }

I use this to add some user defined output to the configuration page of an extension but you can also
you this to execute some initial setup actions.

After installing an extension you can now click on the button "Make updates" to execute your script.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least there as a hook in the old EM ( TYPO3 4.5 and below). I guess there are some in the new one too.

You can add some fields to the view, where you can set your settings.

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SC_OPTIONS']['typo3/mod/tools/em/index.php']['tsStyleConfigForm'][] = "EXT:yourextension/class.yourextension.php:yourextension->main";
```